# Where can I persist what company a user belongs to with ASP.NET MVC and MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-membership

When a user logs on to my ASP.NET MVC application I need to persist what company that  user belongs to.  The company they belong to will determine what database ~all~ their queries come from so it is important for me to query for their company as soon as they log in and persist it so I don't have to perform this lookup again.

Where/How should I store this Company ID?  Session? Some way to customize a MembershipProvider that would allow me to retain this information in a User object?

What would be the best way to handle this?  Literally, every query I do after that will wildly depend on that company ID so it is important that I retain that information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ASP.NET's Profile Properties, but you need to create your own handler for them.  Check out Seventh Element's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/asp-net-mvc-membership-how-to-assign-profile-values/465406) for ideas on how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You could [write your own Auth module](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/AspNetCustomAuth.aspx) to extend [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) and store the company in the IPrincipal.

Then you get to do User.Identity.Company just like [User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx).

This is more up-front work than sticking the company in an already-existing bucket like Cache or Session, but it lets you write some pretty effortless code once you have everything wired up.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it into session, because in your case using the Profile  means 1 additional  roundtrip to DB for every DB call.

If you access the profile anyway in every actionmethod then you should use it offcourse.