# Avoid ProfileCommon creation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, membership, profile, profilecommon

I'm using asp.net profile functionality.
I need to use some profile property names like "test/appname".

When I try to star the web application I get an error about invalid property name. I think the problem is the autogenerated profilecommon class.

I'm accesing profile properties with getters and setters so I don't need the profilecommon class

How can I avoid this class creation?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Website project or a Web Application project?

**EDIT**

[How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/asp-net-membership-how-to-assign-profile-values)

Check the part about having to implement profiles yourself for the Web Project - also MVC AFAIK:
http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx

Comment: It's a web application project, I'm using ASP.net MVC

Comment: I don't speak english. I think I make the wrong question.
I need to avoid the creation of profilecommon.
In my test project I'm using profile properties like: appname1/title1 or appname2/title2
I need the "/" in the name of the property (is a requiremente), and I'm accesing the profile with the profilebase. In the test all work ok, but when I try to use this functionallity in asp.net, I have an error about propery name invalid in the web.config. I think the problem is the dynamic creation of the profilecommon with name properties using "/"

Comment: Can you give a code sample and indicate what type of ASP.NET project this is?

Comment: Here is a code sample, it's a 2.83k rar compressed file

http://www.mediafire.com/?kjmm4mzuvmm

It's only an empty website with the profile section, net 3.5, created with VS2008. You dont need the database to run the website.
If you don't comment the properties with slashes, the website doesn't work

Comment: I cannot open this. Why would you need a slash in a property name?

Comment: Can you not simply use "appname" and resolve any path issue in your code and/or DB?