# Why am I getting a TypeLoadException when defining a custom profile?

Tags: c#, command-line, asp.net-membership, profile

I'm writing a .NET command-line application that will migrate users from an existing database into `aspnetdb`. To simplify the user-specific settings, I'm using the profile class that Joel Spolsky wrote about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/asp-net-membership-how-to-assign-profile-values/1111714#1111714).

It works great in the ASP.NET MVC website, but for some reason it's throwing a `TypeLoadException` when being used from this new application. I'm not sure why the framework is trying to load the new class from `System.Web.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you need to be more specific in the `app.config` file. Instead of writing this

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="MigrationFromUDF.AccountProfile">
```

you need to specify the name of your application (or assembly)

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="MigrationFromUDF.AccountProfile, MigrationFromUDF">
```

Comment: I was sharing a custom profile provider between a MVC web project and an Azure Worker roles and spent ages trying to work out what was wrong. This answer was part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I found it was part of the solution. I found that I also needed to be explicit declaring the assembly for the <Add /> value of the <profile><providers /></profile> section in the app.config on the work role. So that the type key reads 'type="my.custom.ProfileProvider, My.WorkRoleProject"'