# How to add properties to users in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, customization

After I have the initial ASP.NET MVC 2 website and the default Membership provider up, how do I start adding features specific to an user? Like, say, we want to let users choose their favorite products and we want to remember these choices somehow or add a favorite color property to an user?

Where should these customizations go and how should they be associated with the out-of-the-box membership system?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use `profiles` to store user related meta data.

[here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values) to a fine example of implementing profiles in asp.net and while not MVC specific, will provide you with the background you need to take the few additional steps in using profiles in MVC which can be found [here](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1327/profile-provider-in-aspnet-mvc/)