# Missing assembly reference error in web application in VS2008

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page called ProfileInfo.aspx and the codebind looks like this -

```
            using System;
            using System.Web;

            namespace myservice
            {
                public partial class ProfileInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
                {
                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                        // if no postback but user is authenticated, grab info from database
                        if (!IsPostBack)
                        {
                            if (System.Web.Profile.**IsAnonymous** == false)
                            {

                            }


                        }


                    }

                    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

And I am getting an error from the Profile.IsAnonymous statement, as follows -

The type or namespace name 'IsAnonymous' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Profile' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add a .NET dll reference to the web application project? I tried to look for System.Web.Profile but there is no such DLL. Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Context.Profile.IsAnonymous but your intention is probably to read values from profile.

You can't use **Profile** directly in web applications. See [How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values/1111714#1111714)

Comment: Thank You Pavel. That link totally saved my life!!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need an assembly reference.

The `System.Web.Profile` namespace exists in the `System.Web` assembly (which is already added to web applications by default).

`IsAnonymous` is a property of the `ProfileInfo` class.

Do it like this:

```
if (Profile.IsAnonymous == false)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Taken from MSDN:

> When your application runs, ASP.NET
>   creates a ProfileCommon class, which
>   is a dynamically generated class that
>   inherits the ProfileBase class. The
>   dynamic ProfileCommon class includes
>   properties created from the profile
>   property definitions you specify in
>   your application configuration. An
>   instance of this dynamic ProfileCommon
>   class is then set as the value of the
>   Profile property of the current
>   HttpContext and is available to pages
>   in your application.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Profile is a namespace, not a class. You'll need a reference to an actual Profile to check if it's anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Context.Profile.IsAnonymous
```