# aspnet mvc extending membership details using aspnet_users table

Tags: asp.net-membership

I read all posts available referred to the possibility to extend membership and include users details information but at the moment the procedure is not so clear for me. I was wondering if anyone can shed some light providing me a link to:
- a book with an implementation of a users table with foreign key to aspnet_users.
- a tutorial step by step of a users table with foreign key to aspnet_users.
- a microsoft page with detailed information of how to implement users details.

Additionally, same information to implement email verification, password recovery would be great.

Comment: ok, it seems that profile area on web.config could be a possibility instead of users table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically use `profiles` to store user related meta data.

This is a well known procedure and requires only configuration in order to leverage controls and code that conform to the ProfileProvider model.

This is the path of least resistance and the recommended strategy in most cases.

[here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values) to a fine example of implementing profiles in asp.net.

'Extending' and keying off of the aspnet tables would entail customizing the database, writing and testing code to perform your data access. This is the hard road and should be taken only as a last resort and by an experienced developer.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, additionally i found an apress book called pro.asp.net framework displaying the same approach.
thank you, sebastian.