# profile in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)

Hi all:

I want to save some values in Profile in asp.net MVC controller, How can I access the profile object in controller ? What namespace Do I need to add. I have added few name value pairs under profile section in web.config.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values