# ASP.Net - ProfileCommon Save() not working!

Tags: asp.net, save, asp.net-profiles

I have been banging my head over saving the Profile the whole day but couldn't accomplish it.
I am able to create a profile, delete, but not edit the details!

After hustling with it for a while, after looking at the SQL Server Profiler logs, I understood I was indeed saving the details but somehow the same sproc is updating the record with previous details! Tried debugging but neither the page or master page's pageload event was hit!

Could it be a problem with db transaction? But my code has no transaction handling functionality, so I doubt if it has to do anything with rollback or stuff like that!

Here's my code, just in case if someone could find the **bug**!

**web.config**

```
<profile defaultProvider="CustSqlProfileProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="CustSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="connString" applicationName="/save_online"/>
            </providers>
            <properties>
                <add name="FirstName" type="System.String"/>
                <add name="LastName" type="System.String"/>
                <add name="Email" type="System.String"/>
                <group name="Address">
                    <add name="Street" type="System.String"/>
                    <add name="City" type="System.String"/>
                    <add name="PostalCode" type="System.String"/>
                </group>
                <group name="Contact">
                    <add name="Phone" type="System.String"/>
                    <add name="Mobile" type="System.String"/>
                </group>
                <add name="ShoppingCart" type="psb.website.BLL.Store.ShoppingCart" serializeAs="Binary" allowAnonymous="true"/>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

**code**

```
private void UpdateProfile()
    {
        ProfileCommon myprofile = this.Profile.GetProfile(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        myprofile.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.LastName = tbLastName.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Email = tbEmail.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Address.Street = tbStreetPhysical.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Address.City = tbCity.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Address.PostalCode = tbPostalCode.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Contact.Phone = tbPhone1.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Contact.Mobile = tbMobile.Text.Trim();
        myprofile.Save();
    }
```

In SQL Profiler trace

**exec dbo.aspnet_Profile_SetProperties** is executed with right values when ProfileCommon's save() is called and after the page is done loading, the same st.procedure is executed again with previous values. 
How is it called second time?! This is so annoying!!

Would this data from SQL Server Profiler help?

```
 -- network protocol: LPC
    set quoted_identifier on
    set arithabort off
    set numeric_roundabort off
    set ansi_warnings on
    set ansi_padding on
    set ansi_nulls on
    set concat_null_yields_null on
    set cursor_close_on_commit off
    set implicit_transactions off
    set language us_english
    set dateformat mdy
    set datefirst 7
    set transaction isolation level read committed
```

More info:
Admin is able to update profile information of other users but not able update his own profile. And other web site users are also unable to update their profile info!

How strange!

Someone please bail me out!

Comment: Web Application Project or Website Project template?

Comment: My own experience in case when the breakpoints are not hit. Delete all the breakpoints, clean the solutions, add the breakpoints back and then rebuild the solution to get proper debug assemblies. I get this often when attaching to a process and may be your rumtime assembly is a different one than what you are expecting. Even at the same time, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450339/use-a-profile-in-an-asp-net-web-application if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223003/asp-net-profile-save-overwritten-by-old-values) question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [your other profile save question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223003/asp-net-profile-save-overwritten-by-old-values).  Regardless, you do not need to call Save at the end.  This automatically happens if you have the auto save feature turned on in the config.  If you want to explicitly call Save, just turn that setting off and things should work like you expect.