# strong-typed profile values in ASP.NET membership (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, strong-typing, asp.net-profiles

I've been using ASP.NET MVC with membership-based login for several years and everything is working fine (it's now MVC3, but membership didn't change since the first version which was MVC1). Now I need to add a value into the profile (just one value, of very seldom use - so it doesn't warrant custom membership provider or custom tables)

I got it working through `profile.SetPropertyValue("myprop")`, but I would really want to get `profile.myprop` to work. Is it possible?

I saw some advise to have a custom class `MyProfile : ProfileBase` and have myprop as a property of that class. For some reason, casting `ProfileBase.Create(currentUser.UserName)` to MyProfile gives me an error (illegal cast).

Is there an example somewhere of ASP MVC application with Profile, similar to this [Old Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx) by ScottGu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joel Spolsky had a great answer to this question [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values). You're basically on the right track.

If you're getting the illegal cast error, its most likely due to a problem in the config file. Make sure this is included; more specifically the `<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="YourNamespace.AccountProfile">` section.

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="YourNamespace.AccountProfile">
    <providers>
         <clear />
         <add name="SqlProvider"
              type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
              connectionStringName="sqlServerMembership" />
    </providers>
</profile>
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly the post that I was referring to in my third paragraph :)
But I am getting cast error when I am casting ProfileBase.Create to MyProfile class...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it was. Don't know how I missed "inherits" attribute in the original post. Probably, I was coding web.config from MSDN docs that don't apply to Web Projects. Additionally, profile properties should *only* be in the class; not in web config.

Last, in my situation (which I think is common) I am populating profile properties as in Register action. Strangely, the user is **not** logged in at that time (even after `SetAuthCookie()` call. Therefore, rather than using static CurrentUser property, I created static `NamedUser(string userName)` function.