# Asp.net inserting data in profile property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strong-typed profile values in ASP.NET membership (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603527/strong-typed-profile-values-in-asp-net-membership-mvc)

Currently i am inserting data in profile by using this `profile.SetPropertyValue("prop", data);`but i want to know that is there any way so that i can use something like `profile.prop = data;` instead of `profile.SetPropertyValue("prop", data);` to insert data in profile and also get `profile properties in dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you can do that by creating an inherited profile (from ProfileBase)

Not sure if that's still "up-to-date", but it seems it's rather well explained here :

http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx