# Force Change password on first login

Tags: asp.net, security

I'm rying to get my head around doing a "force password change on first login" with a custom Membership Provider, but I can't see properties, or how to make this work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This is not exist on the exist in Membership Provider.

The reason is that is no reason to exist because here the user make their account at the first place and set the password direct by their computers. The "force password change" have a meaning in a computer that some one else (the administrator) make the account for you and he set a temporary password, or the password get from a printed paper that is on some agreement or something like that.

Now, because as you say you make a custom Membership Provider what is stopping you to make a custom field for that ?

You can do that on Profile variables - actually you can add any extra properties there.

About Profile variables

[How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)

[Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

[ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)