# Using Customized Membership in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` in my application , I am using `Asp.Net` built-in membership framework .The installation of `aspnet_regsql` services have been properly installed on my database.The `aspnet_users` table however contains basic information about the user , How do I add additional information about a user.Should I modify the table itself or should I use another table and link it with `aspnet_users` table.Also the `Membership.ValidateUser(username,password)` works well , but I have a requirement where the login is based on the user code.How can I achieve this , is it possible with built-in Membership.
Any suggestions are most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's all possible. You'll have to detail that "usercode' to get a better answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the usercode could be something like 1a , 2a and so on.

Comment: And how do you (not) log in with '1a' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ASP.NET [`Profile-Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx) instead.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx

You can store   any kind of additional information even binary(images).
I've used The [`SqlProfileProvide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx) myself in my current application to let the user himself select his startpage.

Therefor i just needed to add this to the `web.config`:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="RM2ConnectionString" applicationName="/ERP"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Startpage"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

And i could write this property in codebehind:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("Startpage", startPage); //startPage is a String
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.Save();
}
```

and read it in the following way:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Dim user = Membership.GetUser();
    Dim startPage = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("Startpage") as String;
}
```

You can store anything you want, see the link above for further informations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ProfileProvider` ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profileprovider.aspx)).

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

And here: [How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom membership provider by inheriting from `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` - this way you can implement any additional functionality you need. You can then store the user details in your own table structure etc. You'd then point your web.config at your custom provider to use it.

Useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider
- http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256