# Can I add a field to my "Users" database ? (Membership CreateUser Method)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I everyone,

I would like to add one or more field on my register page. I try to add my new field in argument to my Membership.CreateUser() method but it tells me it doesn't support more than 8 args. What can I do ? Develop my own custom provider ? There is no other solution, or trick ?

Excuse me for my english, and I begin in asp, so all you could tell me is well coming. 
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11344585/985284

Comment: What kind of field? Could you perhaps store the extra field in a Profile? Which MembershipProvider are you using?

Comment: I want add one, or two fields nvarchar & I'm using SqlServerCe.4.0 provider. I'm watching to use  the Profile table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a custom provider in order to add fields to the User table (though it may be the proper solution, depending, it's not mandatory).

To add a field to the Users table, go to SQL Server Management Studio, find and expand aspnetdb.  Expand Tables and right click on Users.  Choose Design, add the fields you want and click save.  That's it!

**EDIT: Implementing Profiles**

---

Okay, let's assume you want to add two Profile attributes to your users: FirstName and LastName, both strings (or nvarchar in db terms)

Web.Config
(the name and type are defaults, you'll need to set your connection string for the aspnetdb)

```
<profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="string"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="string"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

So now that you have a profile provider configured and properties defined, you can work with them via the `ProfileBase` class. 
For example, when a new user registers at your site, in addition to the username and password that is required for Membership.CreateUser, you can ask your users to enter their first and last names.  Once they've posted the form back to your server, you'd process it like so:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateUser( ViewModel viewModel )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    MembershipCreateStatus status;
                    var newUser = Membership.CreateUser( viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password, viewModel.EmailAddress, null, null, true, null, out status );
                    if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                    {
                        //set profile data
                        ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(viewModel.UserName);
                        profile["FirstName"] = viewModel.FirstName;
                        profile["LastName"] = viewModel.LastName;
                        profile.Save();
                    }
```

Editing Profile data is the same as creating it.

Getting Profile data for a user is just as easy:

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
var firstName = profile["FirstName"] as string;
var lastName = profile["LastName"] as string;
```

Hope this helps get you going!

Comment: Adding the field is ok, but after I can't access it in my code with the createUser method... Thanks anyway

Comment: Have you considered using profiles?  They may be a simple solution

Comment: You mean the table aspnet_Profile ?

Comment: Hi, even having read msdn doc on Profiles I can't implement it. You tell me it will be a simple solution but I can't see how and where implement it in my code. I've create a new table, I've add fields in my AccountModels.cs, in my view too, but I don't know how access and update data in my new table from my AccountController. I'm desesperate ^^ I don't understand too what is the purpose of defining <profile> <properties> in web.config. It don't seems too hard yet but I'm really stuck

Comment: @Alternative just updated my answer with a bit of detail on profiles and how to use them

Comment: Thanks for you help and time. Do I need to modify applicationName="/" ? I wrote the four lignes ProfileBase... in my Post Method Register, is that good ? And I had my two new properties in my AccountModel too..But when I go to my Register View, my two fields appear well, but they hide content like it was a password when I wrote data, and when I submit the form, I've this error : The connection name 'ApplicationServices' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty. But my info are well updated in my Users and Membership tables, but not my two new properties

Comment: So, I was keep looking, I add a new connectionString like that  `  <add name="ApplicationServices"
   connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;                 AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />` and it seems to work, my Profile table was updated, but my fields always hide content, but it's another issue. I guess I'm good now, thks

Comment: Glad it's working. As far as 'hiding' the input, check that the properties are not decorated with [DataType(DataType.Password)] in your model.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly you must customize your member ship provider

i worked , you can read this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

he helps me in my work

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new table, such as `UserDetail`, and creating your own queries for reading/writing from/to this table.  So after calling `Membership.CreateUser()` if the user has been created, insert you custom data into your custom table.

You could create your own custom membership provider, but in my opinion this is more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
var firstName = profile["FirstName"] as string;
var lastName = profile["LastName"] as string;
```

Where did you put this code?

Comment: Are You asking in answer? Or I miss something?