# is it good to add columns in aspnetdb tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-security

I m developing MVC3 application with SQL Server. For security I am using form based authentication (I need to provide authentication and authorization in application).

Currently user are being managed in aspnet_users table by Membership api. I am not getting any other option but to add columns in aspnet_users table.

I need to add the following other columns in aspnet_users table:

1. CreatedBy User id which create User
2. CreatedOn DateTime
3. EditedBy User id
4. EditedOn DateTime
5. IP Address

I am thinking to write own methods to add these records and not try to disturb aspnet stored procedres.

Any gideance or advice please ? I m sure developers will have such needs.

Comment: No, I would recommend against this. You should regard these tables as a "custom, third-party" component - leave it alone. If you need additional info - create your own tables and just reference the existing tables (foreign keys). I would never modify a third-party provided schema - what happens when the next update of that schema is delivered by that third party??

Comment: No, its not a good idea - marc_s is right, in .NET 4.5 the membership table structure changes entirely. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344585/how-to-extend-aspnet-membership-forms-authentication-tables/11344642#11344642

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Membership User Profile API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to extend custom properties to your users, and not directly add columns to the `aspnet_Membership` and `aspnet_Users` tables.

Take a look at [Defining ASP.NET Profile Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), this should be all you need.

Also by default, each user has a `Comment` column that you could add whatever you want to it in a `string`.

There is also a [Web Profile Builder for Web Application Projects](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx) but I don't think you'll need to go that route.