# profile properties are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

when I add this code to my root web.config under system.web

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="UserId" type="String"/>

  </properties>
</profile>
```

and rebuild my project, the properties don't seem to take.

Profile.UserId does not exist. Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: just going off memory try replacing <properities> with <settings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiles are not implemented out of the box for the Web Application Project template:

http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx

http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/

Have you actually implemented it yet or are you just in the planning stage? If the latter, then the above links should provide some valuable info. This also applies to MVC AFAIK - refer to this question:

[How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values) [Check Joel Spolsky's answer]

Comment: Thx! Making my own Profile class worked for me. I also had to run "aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName" on the database

Comment: The command creates the necessary tables required in order to use profiles.