# ASP.NET Profile Properties - using C# MVC

Tags: c#

I am using C# MVC using .NET 4.0

I am trying to implement the ASP.NET Profile Properties seen at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

First, I added the following in my web.config file. Note that I am trying to store the Location for a given user:

```
    <profile>
     <properties>
      <add name="Location" />
     </properties>
     <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
     </providers>
    </profile>
```

Within my code, I used the following:

After I post, I used the following my in controller:

```
      Profile.Location = model.Location;
```

I am getting an error, Cannot resolve 'Profile'. Has anybody used the Profile Property that can offer any assistance? Note that I wasn't even able to find the class that is mentioned in the article.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profile would have to belong to a User/Member so you would have to load or create a new User before adding any profile properties to it.

[See this SO post on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)