# Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Profile.ProfileProvider'

Tags: asp.net, profile

Im implementing the ASP.NET Profile Provider alongside the Membership Provider using Jon Galloway's (slightly dated) [example here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx):

and Im getting the error **Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Profile.ProfileProvider'**

As per the example, I've created a custom UserProfile inheriting from ProfileBase

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{        
    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
    {
        if (username != null)
        {
            var profile = Create(username) as UserProfile;
            return profile;
        }
    }

    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
    {
        var membershipUser = MembershipProvider.GetUser();
        if (membershipUser != null)
            return Create(membershipUser.UserName) as UserProfile;
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymousAttribute(true)]
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return base["Name"] as string; }
        set { base["Name"] = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm calling above method from a Class library like this:

```
var profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(name);
```

In turn, Im calling that method from a Unit test project, which has an app.config:

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProfileProvider" inherits="NAMESPACE.UserProfile, NAMESPACE">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add
      name="MyProfileProvider"
      connectionStringName="MembershipConnection"
      applicationName="/"
      type="NAMESPACE.UserProfile, NAMESPACE"
      />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Name" type="String"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Inheriting from ProfileBase (like Jon's example) should be enough right? I think i've used all variations on the 'type' and 'inherit' attributes, am I missing something here?

Comment: Where you're using `"NAMESPACE.UserProfile, NAMESPACE"`, this should be `"NAMESPACE.UserProfile, ASSEMBLY"`

Comment: correct, but in my case the assemblyname and namespace was identical :)

Comment: OK, was worth checking. Is it necessary to set the `inherits` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to at least save Profile values using a variation on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)

```
dynamic profile = ProfileBase.Create(UserName);
profile.Name = name;
profile.Save();
```

Not sure how to retrieve that same property yet tho, since ProfileBase has no such method...