# Asp.net: 'ProfileCommon' does not contain a definition for 'save'

Tags: asp.net, profiling

I was working in a web application. i used my coustom profile provider, but i had not access to my values so i red [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values) and used the @colivier answer .

```
dynamic profile = ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
string s = profile.GivenName;
profile.Surname = "Smith";
```

Now my problem is i can not save the profile after setting the values.In

**profile.Save();**

it gives me the error:

```
 **'ProfileCommon' does not contain a definition for 'save'**
```

here is the web.config:

```
  <properties >
    <add name="UserName" />

    <add name="Name"   />

    <add name="LastName"/>

    <add name="Email"/>

    <add name="Level"/>

    <add name="Disabled"/>

  </properties>

</profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error message, it looks like 'save' should have been 'Save' (case sensitivity).