# Storing insecure global info in azure

Tags: azure

This is a question from an interview, and I'm trying to reiterate it. I'm not even sure if it's up to date as Azure is changing quite fast lately. I'll paraphrase, please tell me if question makes no sense.

```
What is the best way to store insecure global information for all users. 

 - a) Azure session storage
 - b) Azure application storage 
 - c) Azure application profile info
 - d) other
```

I don't know that there is something called "Azure session storage". People seem to use TableStorage for session management. Same thing goes for application storage and profile info. Does this question make sense?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about azure - not programming.

Comment: That's why it wasn't asked on `programmers.stackexchange.com`. Do you think only conceptual, algorithms related or abstract questions belong here?

Comment: its really more about what a product supports.

Comment: You're right to a point, but I don't think these things that are provided as options actually exist in the product. And if they do, then this is a conceptual question of deciding between speed, cost, reliability tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question doesn't make an awful lot of sense (though maybe because as you said, you've paraphrased it).

Session Storage (presumably Session State), Application Storage (presumably Application State) and Profile Info (part of the membership/role provider infrastructure) aren't Azure specific technologies. They're part of ASP.net so this would also apply to a asp.net web app outside of azure as well.

For each of those things, there are different ways that they can be backed (in process memory, table storage, sql database, app fabric cache etc...)

I think the key words are "Insecure" and "All Users"

If it's for all users, its something that needs to be stored at an application level. 
If it's "Insecure" or data which doesn't contain any data which needs encryption then you have a few options but I think what they're getting at in the question would be an application profile info.

You can use an Application Level profile to store default values for all users of your website (things like default look & feel, default options etc...)

Have a look at this link here - [How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)

Comment: Thank you. This question is paraphrased from an exam, and it made no sense to me because to best of my knowledge there are no services by names by which they were offered. Now I assume questions date back from beginning of Azure when they were pushing and overstating importance of the service.