# How to add custom field to Asp Net Membership provider?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add a string field "SerialNumber" in my User profile table in SQL with ASP Net membership provider. I can add field directly from the SQL Database but is that right to do it? I tried this article [How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values) but at the end it gives a compilation error which is Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase' to 'ProfileCommon'.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Profile Provider for this.

Alternatively, you could create your own table(s) that store extra user-related data. But you have to create your own tables and creating the code to get and save data to and from these tables, so you can use custom tables in this way allows for greater flexibility and maintainability than the Profile Provider (specifically, the default Profile Provider, SqlProfileProvider, which stores profile data in an inefficient, denormalized manner).

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs)