# Implementing Custom Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, profile-provider

I tried a lot on implementing a custom profile provider in ASP.NET MVC.
I've read lots and lots of tutorials, but I can't find where my problem is. It's pretty similar to [Implementing Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc).

But I'd like to create my own Profile Provider, so I wrote the following class that inherits from `ProfileProvider`:

```
public class UserProfileProvider : ProfileProvider
{
    #region Variables
    public override string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string UpdateProcedure { get; set; }
    public string GetProcedure { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public UserProfileProvider()
    {  }

    internal static string GetConnectionString(string specifiedConnectionString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(specifiedConnectionString))
            return null;

        // Check <connectionStrings> config section for this connection string
        ConnectionStringSettings connObj = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[specifiedConnectionString];
        if (connObj != null)
            return connObj.ConnectionString;

        return null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ProfileProvider Methods Implementation
    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        if (config == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            name = "UserProfileProvider";

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["description"]))
        {
            config.Remove("description");
            config.Add("description", "My user custom profile provider");
        }

        base.Initialize(name, config);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["connectionStringName"]))
            throw new ProviderException("connectionStringName not specified");

        ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(config["connectionStringName"]);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
            throw new ProviderException("connectionStringName not specified");


        if ((config["applicationName"] == null) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationName"]))
            ApplicationName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
        else
            ApplicationName = config["applicationName"];

        if (ApplicationName.Length > 256)
            throw new ProviderException("Application name too long");

        UpdateProcedure = config["updateUserProcedure"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UpdateProcedure))
            throw new ProviderException("updateUserProcedure not specified");

        GetProcedure = config["getUserProcedure"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetProcedure))
            throw new ProviderException("getUserProcedure not specified");
    }

    public override System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValueCollection GetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext context, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection collection)
    {
        SettingsPropertyValueCollection values = new SettingsPropertyValueCollection();

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(GetProcedure, myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", (string)context["FirstName"]);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            reader.Read();

            foreach (SettingsProperty property in collection)
            {
                SettingsPropertyValue value = new SettingsPropertyValue(property);

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    value.PropertyValue = reader[property.Name];
                    values.Add(value);
                }
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            myCommand.Dispose();
        }

        return values;
    }

    public override void SetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext context, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(UpdateProcedure, myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (SettingsPropertyValue value in collection)
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(value.Name, value.PropertyValue);
        }

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", (string)context["FirstName"]);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            myCommand.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Here is my CreateProfile action in my Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateProfile(string Username, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus IsCreated = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;
    MembershipUser user = null;

    user = Membership.CreateUser(Username, Password, "test@test.com", "Q", "A", true, out IsCreated);

    if (IsCreated == MembershipCreateStatus.Success && user != null)
    {
        ProfileCommon profile = (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);

        profile.FirstName = FirstName;
        profile.LastName = LastName;
        profile.Save();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

My procedure usp_GetUserProcedure is nothing special:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUserProcedure] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@FirstName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
END
```

And my Web.Config file:

```
<profile enabled="true"
         automaticSaveEnabled="false"
         defaultProvider="UserProfileProvider"
         inherits="Test.Models.ProfileCommon">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="UserProfileProvider"
         type="Test.Controllers.UserProfileProvider"
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         applicationName="UserProfileProvider"
         getUserProcedure="usp_GetUserProcedure"
         updateUserProcedure="usp_UpdateUserProcedure"/>
</providers>
</profile>
```

But I always get this exception:

> Procedure or function 'usp_GetUserProcedure' expects parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", (string)context["FirstName"]);
```

`(string)context["FirstName"]` is a null value.  Even if you pass in a parameter to a sproc, if the value is null on a required parameter, then you will see this error.  SQL Server (effectively) does not differentiate between a parameter not passed, and one passed with a null value.

You're seeing a SQL error.  This is unrelated to MVC and MVC isn't really causing your problem.  Determine if null is a valid value `context["FirstName"]`, and if so, change your function to accept null values.  If not, find out why `context["FirstName"]` is null.

Also, I don't think this line is going to add your parameter names correctly (with the "@" prefix).

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(value.Name, value.PropertyValue);

Also, since this is MVC, make sure you have a control ***named*** FirstName on the form posting to:

```
public ActionResult CreateProfile(string Username, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName)
```

It reads fields based on the name, not the ID

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's because I'm using a class for my properties, ProfileCommon that inherits from ProfileBase.

```
public class ProfileCommon : ProfileBase
{
public virtual string Label
{
    get
    {
        return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Label")));
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetPropertyValue("Label", value);
    }
}

public virtual string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("FirstName")));
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", value);
    }
}

public virtual string LastName
{
    get
    {
        return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("LastName")));
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetPropertyValue("LastName", value);
    }
}

public virtual ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username)
{
    return Create(username) as ProfileCommon;
}
}
```

You can see that I'm using this class in the Web.Config file:

```
<profile enabled="true"
     automaticSaveEnabled="false"
     defaultProvider="UserProfileProvider"
     inherits="Test.Models.ProfileCommon">
[...]
```

And with ASP.Net MVC, if I wrote my properties in Web.Config, I cannot access them using Profile.PropertyName anymore. Maybe there's a way, but I don't find any examples.