# Implementing a Suspension or Penalty System for Users in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm writing a site in ASP.NET MVC that will have user accounts. As the site will be oriented towards discussion, I think I need a system for admins to be able to moderate users, just like we have here, on Stack Overflow. I'd like to **be able to put a user into a "suspension"**, so that they **are able to log in** to the site (at which point they are greeted with a message, such as, "Your account has been suspended until [DATE]"), but **are unable to do the functions that users they would normally be able to do**.

What's the best way of implementing this?

I was thinking of creating a "Suspended" role, but the thing is, I have a few different roles for normal users themselves, with different privileges.

Have you ever designed a feature like this before? How should I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for good question and having kitteh avatar

Comment: The cat in your avatar is kinda ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me convert a comment to an answer and rape Zach and James answers to provide what I think would be a workable solution without the need to enter the '*custom provider zone*'. While writing custom providers is not terribly complicated it is my experience that if you can get the built in providers to do what you want, even if it requires a smell here or there, is always the best route.

Add a role, say `WellGroomedAndBehavesSelf`, that controls access to things that well groomed and behaved users should have access to.

Implement a profile in your web.config and add a `ReinstateDate` property (or `UngroundedOnDate` ;-D).

When a user misbehaves, remove them from the role `WellGroomedAndBehavesSelf` and set the `ReinstateDate` profile property.

In your login logic, override `OnAuthenticate` and check for a `ReinstateDate` profile property, if present and passed, clear it and add the user to the role `WellGroomedAndBehavesSelf`.

Done and no need for custom providers.

**UPDATE:** 
An alternate approach, and probably more robust preventing users from being grounded forever if somehow the profile gets cleared elsewhere than login logic, is to check for the role `WellGroomedAndBehavesSelf` and if missing, THEN check the profile for `ReinstateDate`. If it has passed or is not present, put the user back into `WellGroomedAndBehavesSelf`.

Same effect, but the subtle change in logic will provide a more robust solution.

**How to implement Profiles:**

If you are using a Web **Site** project look [**here**](http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx).

If you are using a Web **Application** project look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/hhow-to-assign-profile-values/1111714#1111714).

Comment: I think I'm actually going to use this solution. Could you explain the part where you say, "Implement a profile in your web.config and add a ReinstateDate property (or UngroundedOnDate ;-D)"? I'm not really sure how to add a property to the profile in web.config. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I'm kind of new to ASP.NET MVC: where do I create the role? Also, how can I configure the Profile into a SQL Server table?

Comment: @maxim - you should start by reading the documents linked above to get a background on how the profile system works, then you can focus on MVC by reading the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834166/implementing-custom-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc, http://joyofexcellence.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/17/profileprovider-in-an-mvc-world/, OR http://tinyurl.com/2fd63qv ;-p

Answer (score 3):

I think roles is the way to go without writing lots of plumbing code.

Create a role called *Active* which everyone is a member of by default. Then take users out of that role while they are suspended.

Every action you want to deny to suspended users requires the *Active* role. Simples.

Comment: Hold on: Users can belong to more than one role at a time, right? That way, if I have multiple user roles, all users would still be Active, and when suspended, they'd lack Active but still have their general roles.

Comment: I'll try that! Seems like a pretty straightforward plan.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your object model looks like, but I would assume that *any* user could be suspended.

**Edit:** I've thought of an alternate solution which is probably simpler considering that you will need to serialize the data somewhere.  Perhaps you could use a regular `DateTime` on your 'user' object, but initialize it to `DateTime.MinValue` for new users.  Whenever you put a user 'in suspension', set `suspendedUntil` to the time they are suspended until.

```
DateTime suspendedUntil = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Whenever you need to check to see whether a user is in suspension or not, just compare `suspendedUntil` with `DateTime.Now`.  If `suspendedUntil` comes after `DateTime.Now`, you know the user is suspended until the date and time specified.  Otherwise, the user is not suspended.  After a user comes out of suspension, there is no need to modify `suspendedUntil` since it will then be after `DateTime.Now`.

```
bool userIsSuspended = suspendedUntil > DateTime.Now;
```

Serializing the `DateTime` would be a matter of saving the value of `suspendedUntil.ToBinary()` and "rehydrating" it using `DateTime.FromBinary(long)`.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution: I'm going to try both yours and James Westgate's solution tomorrow.