# ASP.NET MVC2 User Profiles

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the easiest way to create users with associated profiles in MVC2?
Is there any library already having such functionality?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/04/01/asp-net-mvc-custom-profile-provider/

you may also wan't to have a look at simular questions:

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc1.)
2. [Implementing Custom Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834166/implementing-custom-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc)