# SqlProfileProvider - can you use Profile.GetProfile() in a project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, sqlprofileprovider

I am attempting to use the SqlProfileProvider in an application and can't seem to use it the way I want to.  I would like to be able to simply call up a profile like this:

```
Profile p = Profile.GetProfile("naspinski");
p.Organization = "new_org";
```

but I can't seem to find the correct way to use the *GetProfile()* that I seem to see scattered around the net.  Is there a way to grab, read and modify profiles?

I am using it in MVC 3 and will *not* be actually logging in as the specific user, this will be pulling users from the db that are specified.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve the profile:

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(HttpContext.Profile.UserName, true);
```

And here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151826.aspx). And a [nice blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx) about custom profiles.