# ASP.NET how to add HttpContext Profile to different user

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 WebApplication project

The following will save user name to my current.profile

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Profile["UserName"] = userName
```

I would like to add a new profile named Company with the value 'MyCompany' to all users.
It should be somthing like that:

```
for all users....
{
    System.Web.HttpContext["SpecificUser"].Profile["Company"] = "MyCompany"
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access everyone's HttpContext, however, you could write it to each profile, assuming you know the user's [profile user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019119/sqlprofileprovider-can-you-use-profile-getprofile-in-a-project).  If you don't have their user ID's handy, you may want to write it to the database directly via a stored procedure.  The main point is you need to write it to the profile DB in order to share it for all users.

Comment: can you share an example how to edit a specific user's profile (reminding that this is WebApplication). thanks!

Comment: A small example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151826.aspx.  See the link I included; you don't need to use the profile as a strong type; I believe you can call `profile.SetValue("Company", "MyCompany")` and that would work.