# extending the default membership provider in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am new to asp.net mvc 2.0.Currently i am having registration page with fields login id,username,password.now i want to add my own custom fields like first name and last name.So tell me to do this, i have to add these fields in asp_membership table .If i have to add then i have to change the built in stored procedures.My situation is if registering the user directly it will go to other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc) feature. That's what it's for.

Comment: please give me the coding if u have and please tell me if i register a user,in which table it is stored .

Comment: What part of the many, many examples of ASP.NET Profiles freely available in the docs and on the web do you not understand?

Comment: hey stuntz,thanks for your answer.I have created a new user using custom membership.But now i want to check whether it is created successfully or not .If it is created successfully i want to redirect it to other page ,if not i will remain in the same page.please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the profiles like @Craig Stuntz mentioned but I find it cumbersome if you have a large number of fields or need to query it frequently.

Another approach would be to create a separate table for the additional fields to compliment the asp_net membership tables.  You can then create a wrapper class that will handle the magic between the asp_net Membership tables and this new table.

Good Luck!

Comment: how to validate the fields of customised registration page while registering the user using cusomised membership provider