# store a small data in other place than database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to save a number in my asp.net mvc3 website in order to not loose last user selection in web site but it is not domain related number so I do not want to store in database.
I tried to save it in a file but I do not have good feeling about this solution.
does any one has any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about storing it in a cookie? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built-in membership and profile providers, you could store the data in profiles. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc) might be able to help some with that.