# Questlon about FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

In LogIn method I have:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.User, false);
```

and to get name of this user we use

```
 User.Identity.Name
```

Is possible to get for example type account from databese?

I mean, during when user is Loging, type account is send (to cookie?). 
And use this type in view using something like User.Identity.Name without using controller.
Is possible to do something like that?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by type account? You can get to the user identity in the view without including it in the controller or viewbag, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: type account... I mean e.g. two type of acount 1. admin  2. supervisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, I think your best bet would be using an [ASP.NET Profile Provider](http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx).  With the Profile Provider, you can do something like:

`HttpContext.Current.Profile.AccountType`

You'll need to do a few things to make it work in MVC.  See here for more info:

[Implementing Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc)

Hopefully this helps, and I'm interpreting your question correctly.