# add additional user info to myaspnetuser table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database, asp.net-mvc-3, implicit

I am working on a hotel managment site and in user signup i used asp.net mysql membership provider and it gives me the database that i want to customize.i want to add a column named `contact_no` in mysql membership provider user table how to do this thing in mvc3.

anybody know about this

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a correct to add a new field to users table . I suggest using profile table if you want to store user personal information . that's cleaner and according to asp.net membership provider structure .

- [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc)
- and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)