# How do I use the Profile object from my Razor views?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, user-profile, razor-2

I have an MVC4 application and I've been following the Pluralsight video tutorials.

I've got my UserProfile table with an added property and it's working great:

```vb
<Table("UserProfile")>
Public Class UserProfile
    <Key>
    <DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
    Public Property UserId As Integer
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property FullName As String
End Class
```

`UserId` and `UserName` are default, but I've added `FullName` and got it working. When I create new users their full name is placed in to the `FullName` field in the database.

**How do I access `FullName` from within a Razor view?**

I don't want to use sessions, ViewData or models. In fact I want this displayed on every page so doing this via a controller is not an option.

I was hoping to access it via `@Profile.Item("FullName")` or `@Profile.PropertyValues("FullName")` but the Profile object is empty. How do I set it?

[image: Profile object is empty.png]

Comment: this is tricky. no perfect approach. how do u feel about sessions?

Comment: I'd use them if I had to, they just seemed like an ugly way of doing it.

Comment: So what is the Profile object used for if it's always empty?

Comment: sorry, just saw this. explain your last comment...

Comment: There is a Profile object available to every view, but it's empty. What's it used for if it's not used for a UserProfile?

Comment: OIC, you mean the Membership profile object? If so, its available everywhere but cannot be bound. its part of the http object.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.aspx

Comment: So I can't easily set that Profile object to my UserProfile? :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx) by Phil Haack. Or [this one](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-change-base-type-of-razor-view-engine-pages/) on develoq

You can create a new Base page for your views that has your Profile object as a property.

```
public abstract class ProfileWebViewPage<T> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
  public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }

  public override void InitHelpers()
  {
    base.InitHelpers();
    //Set your Profile here. 
  }
}
```

Then set it as the base type in the webconfig (in the views folder):

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="MyProject.ProfileWebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Then you can simply access it by this:

```
@Profile.FullName
```

**EDIT**

Okay, sorry, I thought you had the information and was just looking for a way to access it on your pages.

You can't (AFAIK) access custom profile information with the SimpleMembershipProvider. I think you need to be looking into a custom ProfileProvider (http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.co.nz/2012/05/implementing-custom-profile-in-aspnet.html) or check out using SqlProfileProvider ([Implementing Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129/implementing-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc))

Or:

YOu could just use EF to do the data access to go straight to the profile (using what ever DB context UserProfile is under:

```
Profile = (new UsersContext()).UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName = User.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: How do I set my Profile? I tried `Profile = New UserProfile With {.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, .UserName = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, .FullName = "??"`

Comment: That last suggestion is pretty cool and the one I'll go with.